# angular drag and drop and angular horizontal timeline

Tags: angularjs

I tried ngDraggable https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable

but it does not work if I do not have a list of draggable elements (I do not)

I need to drag a div to another div.

Is there a react directive that is simple to use and works with single element drag?

I basically want to drag a div to the timeline taken from:  http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-horizontal-timeline

which means that I will need to make the timeline droppable.

Can I have some pointers on this please?

Comment: Please complete your question with a code example of what you are trying to do. Have you checked if the ngDraggable is suited for your needs?

Comment: If it works only with a list and not otherwise, no it does not help me.